# The load factory settings isn't working

Tags: interface, settings, startup-file

Recently, i have modified my startup layout like the change in measurements of unit and grid etc. Then i saved it as startup file.
now when i reset it to factory settings it changes to factory layout, but when i open a new file it again becomes the customized one.

Answer (score 0):

i came across a solution just now.
What if i load it to factory settings and then save it to startup file.
it worked out, My issue is solved.